# ORACLE: Use static value when defining foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, oracle, enums, foreign-keys

How can I define a foreign key constraint like this in ORACLE:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_STORES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STORE_TYPE 
    FOREIGN KEY ("StoreTable", STORE_TYPE) REFERENCES TEST_ENUMERATIONS (TABLE, VALUE)
/
```

I want to combine all Enum values of several tables in one table.
In order to create a foreign key I need also to check the type of the enum since the value alone is not unique.

I need it like this so I can define the Store_Type as enum (C#) in my program but at the same time I want to make sure the database values are all valid.

For example:

TEST_STORE table:

```
| ID        | ...        | STORE_TYPE 
|-----------|------------|------------
| 324234    |            | 0     
| 324235    |            | 0       
| 324236    |            | 1
```

TEST_ENUMERATIONS table:

```
| ID        | TABLE        | VALUE      | NAME        
|-----------|--------------|------------|-------------
| 567234    | StoreTable   | 0          | NormalStore
| 567235    | StoreTable   | 1          | SpecialStore
| 567236    | AnotherTable | 0          | AnotherType
```

Comment: Create a before Insert trigger on `TEST_STORE` to check the new value of column `NAME`, throw error if value is not in valid list and create the foreign key on `(NAME, STORE_TYPE)`.

Comment: Since the NAME column is apparently confusing I deleted it from my example. I want to check a constant value like 'BlaBla' with the foreign key definition - FOREIGN KEY ('StoreTable', STORE_TYPE) - because VALUE alone is not unique in my TEST_ENUMERATIONS table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a virtual column on `TEST_STORES` whose value is always `'StoreTable'`, and use the virtual column as the first column in the foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_STORES ADD (ENUM_TABLE AS 'StoreTable');

ALTER TABLE TEST_STORES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STORE_TYPE 
    FOREIGN KEY (ENUM_TABLE, STORE_TYPE) REFERENCES TEST_ENUMERATIONS (TABLE, VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_STORES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STORE_TYPE 
    FOREIGN KEY (NAME, STORE_TYPE) REFERENCES TEST_ENUMERATIONS (TABLE, VALUE)
/
```

You will need a unique key on test_enumerations(table,value) as well.

Comment: But instead of the NAME (name of store) I want to check a constant value that is always the same. Like FOREIGN KEY ('BlaBlaBla', STORE_TYPE) ...

Comment: That makes no sense.  The purpose of a FK is to ensure that values in a child table's FK columns are uniquely present in another parent table - it enforces a one to many relationship.

Comment: I just would like to have one generic parent table instead of many for my enum values. But than the FK is only unique in combination with a constant value. I wanted to see if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Then maybe all you need is a unique key on your test_enumerations table on the table and value columns.  Forget the FK.